# Is there a way to drag and drop UI buttons in unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to drag and drop UI buttons in unity 3d?

Can I add two functions to a button?
The first when it is normally clicked it does something.
The second when it is clicked and held, it can be dragged and dropped somewhere else on the screen?

This is the code I have so far but it's not working on the button.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (isDragged)
        {
            transform.position =  Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
    }

    public void OnMouseOver()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isDragged = true;
        }

        
    }
    public void OnMouseUp()
    {
        isDragged = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use unity built-in interfaces,

Use `IPointerClickHandler` to do something when it is clicked and implement another three interface for handling dragging which is `IBeginDragHandler`, `IDragHandler`, `IEndDragHandler`

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    //Detect if a click occurs
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(name + " Game Object Clicked!");
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {

    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }
}
```

References : https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html